# How succint bitvectors in C++ has so low memory usage

Tags: c++, bitset, bitvector, bitstring

I am working with bitsets `std::bitset<29621645>` (i.e. with sizes of 29621645 bits) in C++. Each bitset fills around 29MB, which is a lot.

I fell over a library called `sdsl` which have their own bitset called `sdsl::bit_vector`. I was amazed over the low size with same number of bits as above. When I instantiate `sdsl::bit_vector (29621645)` it's only 3.6 MB. When looking at their code I simply cannot figure out how they are representing such large bitsets with such low memory.

Could someone explain this amazing "trick"?

---

LINK to code: https://github.com/simongog/sdsl-lite/blob/master/include/sdsl/int_vector.hpp
LINK to cheat: http://simongog.github.io/assets/data/sdsl-cheatsheet.pdf

(sidenote: I am aware of not being able to do bitwise operation on the `sdsl::bit_vector`.)

Comment: 29 megabits is 3.6 megabytes, i don't think there is any trick it's simply storing 8 bits in a byte

Comment: 3.6 MB is exactly what you would expect from 29621645 bits stored in contigous memory. There is no trick.

Comment: Custom memory allocation, instead of just using a single byte/int per bit. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool

Comment: But when I store the `std::bitset<29621645> b` as a binary file, it uses 29 megabytes. Is there a way for me to store it as compact? If so, will it be able to do bitwise operations as fast as a regular `std::bitset`?

Comment: @Devolus, not sure that vector bool is different than `std::bitset`.